# Better way to pass userInfo data with NSNotificationCenter in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TapNewProduct" object:self.productID];
```

(or)

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"productID":self.productID};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TapNewProduct" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

Which is better method from above two？

Comment: Your question is not clear so you need to ask what you exact want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both the methods you are gonna get same output. you will fetch the object by notification.object.
but in this,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TapNewProduct" object:self.productID];
```

there is no need to create a dictionary. it can reduce the code.

Answer (score 2):

Your first option abuses the 'sender' parameter of the notification because it's simple. It'll work, but it isn't correct. The idea with that parameter is that you can use it to filter the notifications that you receive. If you'll use it like that then fine, but it isn't for passing user info.

So, the second option is the correct one.

Imagine someone else coming to help on your project in the future - the more your code is written to follow standards the easier it'll be for them to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `object` parameter is the "notificationSender", that is, the object posting the notification.  The `userInfo` parameter is intended to contain information about the the notification and it may be nil.

[More details in Apple's reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:).

Answer (score 0):

`postNotificationName:object:` method invokes `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` with a userInfo argument of `nil`.So basically there is no reason to argue with which one is better than the other.